# How do I tell TypeScript to use a globally installed NPM @types package?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

When I executed `npm install @types/node`, the TypeScript compiler ran fine (`tsc -p tsconfig.json`).

Then I tried installing the package globally (`npm install -g @types/node`) and removed the local folder. I got this compile error:

```
test.ts(1,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.
```

The official typescript website says the following https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

> Using "paths" also allows for more sophisticated mappings including multiple fall back locations. Consider a project configuration where only some modules are available in one location, and the rest are in another

and gives this example:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
        "*": [
            "*",
            "generated/*"
        ]
        }
    }
}
```

I can see the files are in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` so I tried variants of the following but still got an error:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
        "*":[ "/usr/local/lib", "/usr/local/lib/*", "/usr/local/lib/node_modules", "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use the types as a global package?  This should really only be held in your devDependencies, because ultimately .ts files get compiled down to .js files and the types are no longer used.  I'm trying to understand your use case for installing these types in the global space with the local dev space is more traditional. ?

Comment: @KevinMansel I'm new to typescript and node. Is global not how to have a package installed globally for use with multiple projects? How am I suppose to save it for use with multiple projects? and how do I tell typescript where to find it?

Comment: Welcome to node and typescript!  Glad to have you aboard.  I would read through this document here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/tutorial.html  Ultimately...typescript is a superset of javascript.  So everything you build in typescript, gets compiled down to javascript and then you run your js files.  Typesccript is nice because you get all kinds of cool compiler checks and nice to haves in your IDE to help you write really solid javascript programs (basically strongly typed js)  So give it a shot, I think it's a good starting point.

Comment: @KevinMansel thanks. I still have no idea how I'm suppose to do it but creating a softlink (`ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ node_modules`) seems to work well enough. So yay unix solutions?

Comment: One should not rely on packages installed outside the project directory. Using packages not declared in `package.json` breaks the compilation or the execution of the application on other computers.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript doesn't inherently support grabbing type definitions from globally installed NPM packages. See this issue on the TypeScript repo: [Types in globally installed packages not recognized by triple-slash directive #30523](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30523):

> As far as I know, we don't search the global npm install directory when resolving typings. This would result in overhead and is almost never the desired behavior. You should find a way to installing the typings/package into your project itself - [mjbvz](https://github.com/mjbvz) ([on Mar 21, 2019](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30523#issuecomment-475286122))

> Not searching the global packages folder is intentional. - [RyanCavanaugh](https://github.com/RyanCavanaugh) ([on Mar 21, 2019](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30523#issuecomment-475338393))

See also: [Suggestion: NODE_PATH support in module resolution #8760](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8760).

As for how to use the `paths` property of tsconfig files (or others like `typeRoots`) to pigeon-hole this, I don't think there's an easy way to do that *robustly*, given that (if I understand correctly,) globally installed packages are installed under the directory which is [**configurable** by the `prefix` customization point](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/folders#prefix-configuration), which can be configured [at multiple scopes (per-project, per-user, and globally)](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#npmrc-files), and that where exactly NPM installs global packages varies by platform. As far as I know, tsconfig files don't support command substitution, so you couldn't do something like [`$(npm config get)`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-config#get) to "factor" out the complexity of that configurability.

I can think of two reasons one would want this:

- convenience for scripting. In this case, I think you will just have to suck it up or keep looking for other workarounds. Perhaps you could just put all your scripts inside a folder as a single "package" (with a single, shared package.json file)
- saving disk space: try using [PNPM](https://pnpm.io/) instead of NPM. NPM has gotten better, but I think at the time of this writing, PNPM is still ahead in performance (at least disk-space-wise).

Comment: meta note: this answer is quoted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76214703/11107541).