# How can I configure "go to definition" to find globally installed npm modules in VS Code?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm

I am using VS Code to develop code to run on Node.js on an Mac M1. In general, I can use "Go to Definition" to find the definition of a module when I install it locally. However, if I install a module globally, I cannot use "Go to Definition" to find the definition of the module.

How can I configure this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know from reading issue tickets, this is not supported (and therefore not configurable).

If you want to talk directly about VS Code, see [intellisense unable to detect npm global packages
#113523](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/113523) (a VS Code issue ticket), which is closed as "Out of Scope", and another, [No Intellisense for globally installed JavaScript modules #51639](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/51639), which is closed as a duplicate of the TypeScript upstream [Suggestion: NODE_PATH support in module resolution #8760](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8760) (all found by googling "`vscode intellisense for global npm`").

But VS Code's TypeScript IntelliSense is based off of tsserver (part of TypeScript), so that's really where the conversation should start, in which case, see this related question: [How do I tell TypeScript to use a globally installed NPM @types package?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59871695/11107541). From my answer there:

> TypeScript doesn't inherently support grabbing type definitions from globally installed NPM packages. See this issue on the TypeScript repo: [Types in globally installed packages not recognized by triple-slash directive #30523](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30523):
>
> > As far as I know, we don't search the global npm install directory when resolving typings. This would result in overhead and is almost never the desired behavior. You should find a way to installing the typings/package into your project itself - [mjbvz](https://github.com/mjbvz) ([on Mar 21, 2019](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30523#issuecomment-475286122))
>
> > Not searching the global packages folder is intentional. - [RyanCavanaugh](https://github.com/RyanCavanaugh) ([on Mar 21, 2019](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30523#issuecomment-475338393))
>
> [...]
>
> As for how to use the `paths` field of tsconfig files to pigeon-hole this, I don't think there's an easy way to do that robustly, given that (if I understand correctly,) globally installed packages are installed under the directory which is [**configurable** by the `prefix` customization point](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/folders#prefix-configuration), which can be configured [at multiple scopes (per-project, per-user, and globally)](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#npmrc-files). As far as I know, tsconfig files don't support command substitution, so you couldn't do something like [`$(npm config get)`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-config#get) to "factor" out the complexity of that configurability.
>
> I can think of two reasons one would want this:
>
> - convenience for scripting. In this case, I think you will just have to suck it up or keep looking for other workarounds. Perhaps you could just put all your scripts inside a folder as a single "package" (with a single, shared package.json file)
> - saving disk space: try using [PNPM](https://pnpm.io/) instead of NPM. NPM has gotten better, but I think at the time of this writing, PNPM is still ahead in performance (at least disk-space-wise).