# How to have Node.js variables auto-completion globally in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

This question is similar to this thread:
[How to enable Node.js code autocompletion in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60777494/how-to-enable-node-js-code-autocompletion-in-vscode)

However, I don't understand why I do not have this feature set up globally. I am trying to work with `.js` files, my VSCode's language is properly set-up. But I don't get why I don't get auto-completion for variable like `process`:

[image: suggestion of process]

I have `node` installed in my machine, I've even tried by installing `npm install @types/node -g` but it doesn't change anything.

And talking with other developers, it seems they don't have this issue. I've tried disabling all my extensions, but it doesn't change.

Is there a setting I am missing?

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/75441946/11107541 and upvote if helpful. I'd vote to close this as a duplicate, but I can't until any answer there is upvoted or accepted.

Comment: Not sure if it answers my problem.

Comment: why doesn't it?